# Darken Behind Text in CSS Without Shadow?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to darken the area behind my text because it makes it mare legible in some places (I just need this in my hero). Right now I'm using multiple shadows with a lot of blur (see below) but this makes the gradient rather rough, and isn't the smooth, "glossier" look I'm going for.

Here's an image of what it does:

[image: Problematic shadowing]

But what I actually want is something more like the shadow here:

[image: Good shadowing]

Is there a way to make an object or something that surrounds the text or is the shape of the text?

Thanks! And here's what I'm using now:

```
text-shadow: 0px 0px 80px rgba(0,0,0,1),
             0px 0px 70px rgba(0,0,0,1),
             0px 0px 60px rgba(0,0,0,1),
             0px 0px 50px rgba(0,0,0,1),
             0px 0px 40px rgba(0,0,0,1),
             0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,1);
```

Comment: Wrap the text in an element and apply `background-color`?

Comment: use a shade of grey instead of black and decrease the opacity in your shadows.

Comment: Is this you are looking for:  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px  rgba(0,0,0,0.6); check it out - http://jsfiddle.net/TLBEx/5/

Comment: David, is there a way to fade on each edge of the background?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single shadow with much smaller radius and a semi-transparent color. That gives a shadow closer to the characters, that is mostly only seen on the lighter part of the background, and that's where it is needed to make the text distringuishable from the background.

Example:

```
text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XFhJa/

Comment: That's a bit better! But is there a way to draw a shape around the text somehow? Because what I really want is something thats not around each character.

Comment: @kylebshr: You can experiment with a larger radius, and perhaps shadows offset in different direction, that gives you more of a shape than a shadow: http://jsfiddle.net/XFhJa/1/